# jQuery not linking with html correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to html/css/jquery but I started working on a little sample webpage. I uploaded the files to godaddy where I am hosting the site but am having trouble getting the jquery portion to work. Not sure if I am not linking the .js file to the .html file correctly or if there is another issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Sample Webpage</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="faq.css" />
            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
            <script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
            <script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='faq.js'></script>
        </head>
```

here is the jquery that I am trying to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#FAQmenu').accordion({
        event: "click",
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a missing `</script>` after this <script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">`

Comment: Well, with the HTML code you are showing, your jQuery code does nothing of course. Could you please provide more code and possibly update this fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/3LJPj/

Comment: I updated the fiddle with the html and css that I am linking to and it appears to work there. This makes me think it is an issue with the linking or with godaddy

Comment: fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3LJPj/5/

Comment: Well, that's why I love asking for a fiddle. ;-) As we have no more info, it's very hard to help. Maybe double check all links again, see if your browser's error log shows errors, test with stupid things like an `alert('test')` and so on.

Comment: try put the absolute path for the `faq.js`, see if helps. That is, http://urdomain/etc/etc/etc`. If you are testing on IE without localhost, you gotta 'accept' to open activex controllers (that will actually run the JS).

Answer (score 1):

You have not closed the first script tag. Instead try:

```
<script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: as embarrassing as that was, it still did not fix the issue :'(

Comment: is `faq.js` placed in same directory as your `html` ?

Answer (score 0):

You must install xampp/wamp/mamp/etc or to upload your files to a server if you want the Google hosted jquery to work, otherwise you can download jquery  and link it from your project folder.

Comment: Why should it be necessary to install anything to link to hosted files?

Comment: Just try to use the Google hosted library from a folder on your computer and see if it works

Comment: I really don't know what you mean. e.g. if you have a html file with something like `<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`, it does not matter if you host that html file on a server or call it locally from a directory (with `file:///...`). The browser makes the request anyway, Google would not even know if the file is hosted or not.